# Does ReadProcessMemory/WriteProcessMemory access program data or code?

Tags: c++, c, winapi

I want to know, if `WriteProcessMemory` or `ReadProcessMemory` functions access program code, or data. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can access both.

Program text and data live in the same address space, and are somewhat intermingled for things like read-only data.